# Module Theory, Free Modules, Finitely Generated Modules

Tags: free-modules

I want to prove that if R is a PID and M is a finitely generated  R-module, then there exist a free R- module F such that

$M \cong F \oplus M_{\text{tors}}$

So, in order to prove the above I set $M/M_{\text{tors}} = F$ and since R is a PID then it is also an integral domain, hence $M/M_{\text{tors}}$ is torsion free, ie F is torsion free. Also, since M is finitely generated the same goes for F, so we have that F is torsion free and finitely generated, hence F is a free R-module. Now, I don't know why, but I am stuck. How to conclude that there is indeed the  isomorphism between M and $F \oplus M_{\text{tors}}$? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you so much Leonardo for the edit.

Comment: So i just gave the answer to myself. I have a previous result that if M is R-module and N is a submodule such that the quotient of M/N is free then M is isomorphic to the direct sum of M/N and N.

Comment: Be careful, you are using a specific result stating that on a PID, every finitely generated and torsion free module is indeed free. I don't know if you are aware of this fact. This is not true anymore if you drop the "PID" assumption. For example, take the $\mathbb Z[X]$-submodule of $\mathbb Z[X]$ generated by $X$ and $2$ (i.e. the ideal $\langle 2, X \rangle$ of $\mathbb Z[X]$).

Comment: Yes indeed. I should've written that since F is finitely generated and torsion free and R is a PID then F is free.